# Video stream optimization

Tags: go, video-streaming

I am building a video surveillance app, for learning purposes.

At the moment I have a very basic prototype working.

I am capturing and sending webcam frames to a browser over a websocket.

Just for some context on how basic the implementation is, on the client side I have:

```
<img id="frame" src="">
```

I am appending the frames via javascript.

The app and the server are written in Golang

Although what I have works, I know sending individual frames to a browser is never going to cut it if I want to view the stream from outside my home network.

I have to optimize the process.

So far I have only thought of compressing the cam frames before sending them to the client.

Also encoding the frames to video and implementing a video player on the client side.

What else can be done?

I know the question is broad, but I assume there must be a standard optimization pattern for video streaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video compression is amazingly efficient, you will never get anything better than that. Look at H.264 for instance https://sidbala.com/h-264-is-magic/